# Toast notification interval time on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm going to make a simple toast notification using periodic task of background agent, what I'm asking is how can I show deep toast notification in specific time (ex:5 mins). Note: We have used this method ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(string name, TimeSpan delay) to check in Emulator.
Is this will work in Device with customized time interval?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Periodic agents typically run every 30 minutes. To optimize battery
>   life, periodic agents may be run in alignment with other background
>   processes and therefore the execution time may drift by up to 10
>   minutes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforPeriodicAgents

You can however send a toast via push notification service. You can do that whenever you want.